# PHP: allow_url_include

Tags: php, security

Quick...possibly stupid question.

When allow_url_include is set to off, does that prohibit other computers from remotely including the files on my site, or does it say that I'm not allowed to remotely include files from other sites?

Comment: This option is [deprecated as of PHP 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.deprecated.php#migration74.deprecated.core.allow-url-include), and it is likely to be removed in the near future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Settings in **your** php.ini only affect **your** PHP installation

Answer (score 6):

Setting `allow_url_include` to `off` in **your** configuration means that **your** PHP code on **your** server will not be able to include remote files.

But it doesn't change anything for other servers, which might request files from your server, like anyone can from the web -- note, though, that if some PHP file is requested, it'll be interpreted, and its output *(not its content ! )* will be sent.

Comment: So, let's say my file is a.php and code is echo $file;  Does that mean that if a file b.php on a remote server includes a.php they cannot set $file before calling my file?  I would assume this to be correct if only the output if returned.

Comment: if register_globals is not enabled (it should not be), then, no, the remote server cannot inject a value into $file.

Answer (score 6):

As said in the php manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include 
is for including remote files, only if you let your directory to reach the source, others can include your php files.

Then is the second suggestion

Comment: ^^ AGREED ^^ add one more

Answer (score 4):

It's **always** impossible to include PHP **code** from properly installed server, no matter of this configuration setting.

At the same time no PHP configuration setting can forbid **HTTP clients** from requesting resources from your HTTP server.