# URL file access in php

Tags: php

I am trying to include my header,footer and sidebar files like this,

```
include($str_url.'header.php');
include($str_url.'sidebar.php');
include($str_url.'footer.php');
```

i have defined `$str_url = "http://www.example.com/";` in my constant file,

But is not working in my server.
how can i fix it?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: _Never_ include remote files (and as a sidenote: `$$str_url` is obviously not a constant. Use constants instead `define()`)

Comment: -1. use [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=include+url).

Comment: probably your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633813/php-allow-url-include)

Comment: I'm assuming the "http://www.example.com/" is actually set to your sites url?  is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

You most probably **don't** want to `include` URLs into your main php file, but the local .php-files. `include ('/path/to/a.php');` instead of `include ('http://url/to/a.php');`

(source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 2):

You probably need modify php.ini   allow_url_include = On.

But better never include files via http.

Answer (score 1):

You should never include files via an absolut URL, because you will not be including the actual code, but the result of it.
Instead use relative paths or server paths (/home/user/public_html)
Easiest way would be via relative paths.
For example, if you have index.php and header.php in the same folder, you can just use:
    include('header.php');
If the files, are in another folder, for example you have header.php in an 'includes' folder, than you would use in your index.php:
    include('includes/header.php');